# WP_User_Query with combined meta query - not working?

Tags: users, user-meta, meta-query, wp-user-query

I'm trying to use `WP_User_Query` class to list all users basing on their specific `meta` fields.

When I use simple single-meta query, it works fine:

```
$q = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'role' => 'contributor',
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
        'meta_key'  => 'first_meta',
        'meta_value' => '2'
    ) );
```

but when I try to make combined two-field query and find users that have had filled `second_meta` meta field, the query lists all contributors (meta query is not working at all):

```
 $q = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'role' => 'contributor',
        'fields' => 'all',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            0 => array( 
                'meta_key'  => 'first_meta',
                'meta_value' => '2'),
            1 => array(
                'meta_key' => 'second_meta',
                'meta_value' => '',
                'meta_compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    ) );
```

How can I make this combined meta query work?

Of course I'm trying to find all users that are contributors, have `first_meta`==2 AND `second_meta` is not empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using wrong parameters, please try this instead (untested):

```
$q = new WP_User_Query( 
    array(
        'role'          => 'contributor',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'  => 'AND',
            array( 
                'key'     => 'first_meta',
                'value'   => '2',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'second_meta',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    ) 
);
```

where we've used the `key`, `value` and `compare` parameters within the `meta_query` array. I've also removed the `'fields' => 'all'` part, because it's set by default.

Comment: Easy mistake, shame on me ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happens to the best of us, good you worked it out

Comment: @birgire how do i go with multiple user role using your code just check link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871458/how-to-fetch-wp-user-query-with-multiple-role-arguments/33871677#33871677

Comment: Good question, wait for WordPress 4.4, that's just around the corner and use the new  `role__in` attribute ;-) @SanjayNakate